# "this" not accessible in embedded function used for Effects

Tags: javascript

Regarding the object below I am getting a " 'this' is undefined error".  This only occurs in the next() function block...as commented below, if it is placed in the Effects function block there is no error.

This is only test code...my goal is to pass the element in through the constructor.  This test code has it passed in from both the constructor and the function because I'm testing it.  Once it passes I will take out the function argument from fade().

Also the Object Usage, happens to be in another object, that is why you see "this" there as well.

**Object Usage:**

```
var EffectsObject = new Effects( this.element );
EffectsObject.fade( this.element, 'down', 4000);
```

**Object Definition:**

```
var Effects = function( element ) 
{
    this.element2 = element;
};

Effects.prototype.fade = function( element1, direction, max_time ) 
{
    Effects.elapsed = 0;
    this.element2 = foo;      // works here but not if I put it in next();
    function next() 
    {
        Effects.elapsed += 10;
        if ( direction === 'up' )
        {
            element2.style.opacity = Effects.elapsed / max_time; // fails here
        }
        else if ( direction === 'down' )
        {
            this.element2.style.opacity = ( max_time - Effects.elapsed ) / max_time;
        }
        if ( Effects.elapsed <= max_time ) 
        {
            setTimeout( next, 10 );
        }
    }
    next();
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a variable that is in the lexical scope of the the `next` function.

`var that = this;`

above `next`, and use `that` in `next`.

```
var that = this;
function next() {
// use "that" here
... 
}
```

The problem is when you define a method on a prototype, and then execute that method on the instance of an object, the context of the method (the scope) is set when you call the method.  When that happens `this` points at the instance  on which the method was invoked.

When you defined `next`, note it's not part of any prototype.  It's just a function.  When you execute it, the context of the execution (i.e. `this`) is not the instance of the object.

When you define `that`, and then use it in the function, `that` is in the lexical scope of the `next` function.  When you invoke `next`, a closure is created, locking the value of `that` into the execution scope of `next`.

Comment: why is "element1" accessible in next on and not "this"

Comment: because `element1` is defined in the arguments of `fade`

Comment: honestly this seems more like a JavaScript bug or inconsistency.  The function parameter is transferred inwardly in scope but "this" is not.  Note - Parameter is what is in the definition, argument is the value passed in...this is the terminology / semantics I use.

Comment: remember `this` is a special word in javascript.  it always refers to the current context of execution.